# Pass array or list parameter by StoredProcedure (Spring, Java)

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I would like to pass array or list parameter by StoredProcedure but I have no idea how I can do it.

```
DB side:
CREATE TYPE ownType AS TABLE(
   ids [nvarchar](50)
)

ALTER PROCEDURE db(
   @Ids AS ownType readonly
)

Java side:
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(@Ids, Types.Array, "ownType"))

Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
                .put(@Ids, "List or Array java object")
                .build();

StoredProcedure.execute(params)
```

When I execute it I get the following error message:

```
SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The conversion from UNKNOWN to ARRAY is unsupported.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to ARRAY is unsupported.",
```

Does anybody have experiences about how I can use it, what the problem is?

Thanks for your answer in advance!